# Unable to set values in the map using webclient call response

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am unable to get values filled in the map after making a web client call and  using the response of the previous Mono.Here is the code I have tried.The value of parameters.size() comes out to zero.Not able to get the reason as to why the value is not filled.I basically want to return age ( and not Mono object)
 from this method.Using block gives an error block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-3.

```
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>();
 Mono<Person> obj = webClient
    .post()
    .uri("dummy url")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(Person.class)
 .flatMap(resp -> {
 parameters.put("name", resp.getName());
 parameters.put("age", resp.getAge());
 return Mono.just(new Person(resp.getName(),resp.getAge()));        
 }

     );
```

System.out.println(parameters.size());

Please suggest where I am wrong and solution to fix the same.

Comment: could you provide more context about why you'd need those parameters for? I can explain why this doesn't work but can't give a solution to that without understanding the use case you're trying to solve.

Comment: This is just a dummy example I have used to simulate the real use Case.In general I would need a verification token to be returned from this method which will be used to make future webClient calls using the token returned from this method in the headers.So basically another method calls this method to get the token and use that in future get/post requests.I can get a Mono Object with this call but need to extract token out of it to return it and use it

Answer (score 1):

Since this is about collecting and using a token of some sort collected from a previous HTTP call, your best bet is to delegate all that to an `ExchangeFilterFunction`.

An `ExchangeFilterFunction` is a filter that is executed on the client side for each outgoing request. Here is a very, very naïve implementation of such a filter:

```
class TokenFilterFunction implements ExchangeFilterFunction {

    private final AtomicReference<String> token = new AtomicReference<>();

    @Override
    public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest req, ExchangeFunction next) {
        if (this.token.get() == null) {
            return fetchToken(next).then(sendRequest(req, next));
        }
        else {
            return sendRequest(req, next);
        }
    }

    private Mono<ClientResponse> sendRequest(ClientRequest req, ExchangeFunction next) {
        ClientRequest request = ClientRequest.from(req)
                .header("Token", this.token.get()).build();
        return next.exchange(request);
    }

    private Mono<Void> fetchToken(ExchangeFunction next) {
        ClientRequest tokenRequest = ClientRequest.create(HttpMethod.GET,
                URI.create("https://example.com/token")).build();
        return next.exchange(tokenRequest).doOnNext(res -> {
            this.token.set(res.headers().header("Token").get(0));
        }).then();
    }
}
```

This could automatically call the token endpoint to fetch a token when needed and directly chain with the request you asked in the first place. Again, such an implementation should be much more complex than that, handling domains, errors, and more.

If you're using some authentication technology, such a filter might be implemented already in Spring Security in a much, much better way.

You can configure it on your client during the building phase, like:

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().filter(new TokenFilterFunction()).build();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Brian.This really helps.2 Questions around this.

req.headers().set("Token", this.token.get()); This throws an error saying java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
 at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.put(Collections.java:1457) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
 at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.java).Basically trying to modify a immutable object.
Secondly, while creating tokenRequest

This will again be a webclient get call (returned in Mono object) which needs to be  mapped and set to token variable.How to achieve this.

Thanks a lot

Comment: 1) I've updated my answer to create a new request out of the existing one. My bad. 2) This is more or less what the code snippet is already doint; if the token is in the response body, you could use `retrieve()` instead of `exchange` and something like `bodyToMono(Token.class)` to extract the information.

Comment: Yes, able to fix the issue after that and now able to send a request successfully.Just one strange issue though.The get call works perfectly fine for the first time when I run the application but fails second time on wards with bad request error and show the same behavior on restarting the application, whereas works fine every time if I hardcode the header in the get call ( not use the exchange filter logic).Any idea why? Is it that some thread is not killed or something after the first time or any other reason. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Error Log :2018-07-24 12:11:07.597  INFO 9308 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Mono.Map.3 : onComplete()
2018-07-24 12:11:07.597  INFO 9308 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Mono.Log.4 : onComplete()
2018-07-24 12:11:07.607 ERROR 9308 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Mono.FlatMap.5.org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException: ClientResponse has erroneous status code: 400 Bad Request
 at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.lambda$createResponseException$7

Comment: I am not going to debug code with very little info in the comments section. I don’t know what your remote token endpoint is sending, what are the http request/response headers, etc. This is turning into a whole new question that has nothing to do with the original one.

Comment: Getting this error after implementing the exchange filter logic functionality , that also it works fine for the first attempt.And as I said works fine everytime if header is hardcoded in the get call. Looks to be some issue with DefaultResponseSpec as seen in the console.  Any leads where I can check for possible reason for this issue or probably create a new question, but again the info related to the issue would remain the same?

Thanks a lot!